# how to use ckeditor with wiris plugin in angular 4

Tags: angular, ckeditor, wiris

I am not able to add ckeditor with (wiris math equation) plugin and use in angular 4 with external Js file stored in asset. ng2-ckeditor and ngx-ckeditor works well but doesnot have ability to add plugin(wiris math equation) inside it.

I want to use as an exernal js file. not with the help of any npm packages.

Comment: You can try and add the js in scripts array in angular.json(v6 and above). it will the js available globally tot he app.

Comment: i have tried these steps but ckeditor gives error. will you please give me a dummy project of ckeditor with external js. Its a kind favour from your side.

Comment: Ohh . Ok I will try to workout something and let you know.